# Custom Menu with Icons

Tags: magento-1.7, php, category, navigation

I need to add icons before each categories in my main menu. Is there any extensions for that or can u provide the details to edit which of the files in magento

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help. Even though this is not an extension you can refer the content in this link and modify the source as you want.

http://www.h-o.nl/blog/using_category_images_in_your_magento_navigation/